# aws s3 sync behavior different than linux cp and rsync when copying folders and their contents

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Am I missing something here?

On Linux

`cp -r ./test1/ test2/`

results in `test1/` INSIDE of `test2/`

`rsync -r ./test1/ test2/`

results in `test1/` INSIDE of `test2/`

`rsync -r ./test1 test2/`

results in CONTENTS of `test1/ inside of` test2/`

With `aws s3 sync`

`aws s3 sync ./test1/ s3://mybucket/`

results in the CONTENTS of `test1/` in `s3://mybucket/` instead of the `test1/` folder INSIDE the s3 bucket like `s3://mybucket/test1/CONTENTS`.

Is this on purpose? Is there anyway to force the interaction to be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
aws s3 sync ./test1/ s3://mybucket/test1/
```

Or, you can sync the *current* folder, but specify which paths to include:

```
aws s3 sync . s3://mybucket/ --exclude "*" --include "test1/*"
```

See: [AWS CLI: Use of Exclude and Include filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)

Comment: Thanks, the first option is the only way I knew how to get it to do it, but was wanting to avoid having to enumerate every folder twice (once in the source and destination). Your second option kind of gets me there. Very interesting use of include/exclude and wouldn't have thought of that method.